# Unexpected result when displaying static html table in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want to display a html-table in a shiny page. The table is generated by a function and uses the following data:

```
rep_loop <- data.frame(Activity = LETTERS[1:3], ID_resource_rep = sample(1:10, 3),
  Div_resource_rep = sample(1:10, 3),
  ID_resource_loop = sample(1:10, 3),
  Div_resource_loop = sample(1:10, 3))

build_table <- function(data){
  html.table <- 
    tags$table(style = "border:1px solid black; padding: 3%; width: 80%",
      tags$tr(
        tags$th(" "),
        tags$th(colspan = 2, "Repeat (Act-X-Act)"),
        tags$th(colspan = 2, "Selfloop (Act-Act)")
      ),
      tags$tr(
        tags$th(" "),
        tags$th("Same Resource"),
        tags$th("Other Resource"),
        tags$th("Same Resource"),
        tags$th("Other Resource")
      ),
      tags$tr(
        tags$td(data$Activity),
        tags$td(data$ID_resource_rep),
        tags$td(data$Div_resource_rep),
        tags$td(data$ID_resource_loop),
        tags$td(data$Div_resource_loop)
      )
  )  
  return(html.table)
}
```

This is the result from

```
test <- build_table(rep_loop)

<table style="border:1px solid black; padding: 5%; width: 80%">
  <tr>
    <th> </th>
    <th colspan="2">Repeat (Act-X-Act)</th>
    <th colspan="2">Selfloop (Act-Act)</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th> </th>
    <th>Same Resource</th>
    <th>Other Resource</th>
    <th>Same Resource</th>
    <th>Other Resource</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
Warning messages:
1: In charToRaw(enc2utf8(text)) :
  argument should be a character vector of length 1
  all but the first element will be ignored
2: In charToRaw(enc2utf8(text)) :
  argument should be a character vector of length 1
  all but the first element will be ignored
3: In charToRaw(enc2utf8(text)) :
  argument should be a character vector of length 1
  all but the first element will be ignored
4: In charToRaw(enc2utf8(text)) :
  argument should be a character vector of length 1
  all but the first element will be ignored
5: In charToRaw(enc2utf8(text)) :
  argument should be a character vector of length 1
  all but the first element will be ignored
```

I would expect that build_table would return a table with a header, followed by data-lines. The header is as expected but instead of using all the rows from the data.frame, it shows only the first line, followed by 5 warnings.

Where did I make a mistake?

Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you can't have a vector in a `tags$td`. Do:

```
rep_loop <- data.frame(Activity = LETTERS[1:3], ID_resource_rep = sample(1:10, 3),
                       Div_resource_rep = sample(1:10, 3),
                       ID_resource_loop = sample(1:10, 3),
                       Div_resource_loop = sample(1:10, 3))

build_table <- function(data){
  html.table <- 
    tags$table(style = "border:1px solid black; padding: 3%; width: 80%",
               tags$tr(
                 tags$th(" "),
                 tags$th(colspan = 2, "Repeat (Act-X-Act)"),
                 tags$th(colspan = 2, "Selfloop (Act-Act)")
               ),
               tags$tr(
                 tags$th(" "),
                 tags$th("Same Resource"),
                 tags$th("Other Resource"),
                 tags$th("Same Resource"),
                 tags$th("Other Resource")
               ),
               mapply(function(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5){
                 tags$tr(
                   tags$td(x1),
                   tags$td(x2),
                   tags$td(x3),
                   tags$td(x4),
                   tags$td(x5)
                 )
               }, data$Activity,
                  data$ID_resource_rep,
                  data$Div_resource_rep,
                  data$ID_resource_loop,
                  data$Div_resource_loop, 
               SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
    )  
  return(html.table)
}

build_table(rep_loop)
```

---

```
<table style="border:1px solid black; padding: 3%; width: 80%">
  <tr>
    <th> </th>
    <th colspan="2">Repeat (Act-X-Act)</th>
    <th colspan="2">Selfloop (Act-Act)</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th> </th>
    <th>Same Resource</th>
    <th>Other Resource</th>
    <th>Same Resource</th>
    <th>Other Resource</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```